# Rank of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, tensor-products

I have read that given a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$, the maximal number of $\mathbb{Z}$-linear independent elements is given by $\operatorname{rank}M=\dim_\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}M)$. However I do not understand, how $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}M$ becomes a $\mathbb{Q}$-module. A priori, both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $M$ are only $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and tensoring over $\mathbb{Z}$ should yield another $\mathbb{Z}$-module. What am I missing here?

After understanding the above I would also like to know, if we can replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by other (commutative rings)? Or do we need domains here, so that we can build a field of fractions?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the multiplicative set $S= \mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$. Then
$$\mathbb Q\simeq S^{-1}\mathbb Z.$$
Now, in general you have that, if $M$ is an $A$-module and $S$ is a multiplicative set of $A$, then
$$S^{-1}A\otimes_AM \simeq S^{-1}M, $$
that is naturally a $S^{-1}A$-module.

This shows that this definition of rank of an $A$-module holds whenever $A$ is  a domain. If $A$ is not a domain i know that one of the possible definitions of rank of a module $M$ (I read it in some book that i don't remember) is

$$rank(M)=\max\left\{rank_{A/p}(M/ pM) \;|\; p \mbox{ minimal prime ideal of } A \right\}.$$

Comment: Thank you, so far. But what does $S^{-1}\otimes_A M$ mean? Is this a tensor product of modules? Which module does $S^{-1}$ denote?

Comment: it was a mistake, sorry. Now it is correct. It is $S^{-1}A\otimes M$

Comment: Ok, so in our special case $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Q}$, right? I still don't get how this induces a $\mathbb{Q}$-module structure on $\mathbb{Z}$. Or do I still misunderstand you?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if $M$ is a $\mathbb Z$-module then $\mathbb Q \otimes M$ is a $\mathbb Q$- module, since $\mathbb Q\simeq S^{-1}\mathbb Z$. In our special case $\mathbb Q \otimes_{\mathbb Z} M \simeq S^{-1}M$ (and it is a $\mathbb Q$-module).

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. Thank you.